# React renders previous state on state change

Tags: reactjs

This is a simplified version of my code, where I am having a problem.

```
 const Certificates = () => {
  const [currentList, setCurrentList] = useState(false);
  const [sort, setSort] = useState('posted');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (gameDetails) {
      setCurrentList({})
    }
  }, [gameDetails])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sort === 'alphabetical') {
      setCurrentList([])
    }
  }, [sort])

  return (
    <>
      {
        currentList && sort === 'posted' && Object.keys(currentList)
      }
      {
        currentList && sort === 'alphabetical' && currentList.map
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

I have a state variable which changes from `Object` to `Array` depending on the **active sort**.

I have a conditional rendering where if the **sort is 'posted'** it must do the rendering considering the state variable is a `Object`.
if the **sort is 'alphabetical'**, it must do the rendering considering the state variable is a `Array`.

The problem is when the state variable changes from `Object` to `Array`, I am getting a `currentList.map is not a function` error.

When rendering react is considering currentList as a `Object` even though its changed to a `Array`.

The proof for the above statement is:
I tried doing this:

```
<div>
    {
      currentList && console.log(currentList)
    }
  </div>
```

When the state variable changes to an `Array` this is the log I am getting:

```
-> {20/09/2022: Array(1), 18/01/2022: Array(1), 30/06/2021: Array(1), 24/06/2021: Array(5)}
-> [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

When the state changes React first tries to render the previous state, that is where the error is occurring.

How can I solve this, any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you rely on `useEffect` to update `currentList` *after* `sort` has been updated, you will get one render where they are mismatched. Just make a function / functions to set them both at once.

```
function setToPosted(){
  setSort('posted');
  setCurrentList({});
}

function setToAlphabetical(){
  setSort('alphabetical');
  setCurrentList([]);
}
```

---

Alternatively you can just check if the value is an array or not

```
<>
      {
        currentList && !Array.isArray(currentList) && Object.keys(currentList)
      }
      {
        currentList && Array.isArray(currentList) && currentList.map
      }
</>
```

Comment: you mean, whatever changes the sort.Instead of changing the sort and acting on the side effect, you are suggesting to directly set the currentList, am I right?

Comment: Yes, since in this case the two need to be synchronized. Side effects need the component to render before they take effect, as you saw.